# repick image with Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I have a problem repick an image.

I select an image at the first time and everything works fine.
The problem starts when I try to repick an image and the image I picked doesn't appear and there is no bitmap data.

[image]

**onClick button to pick an image**

```
  imagePickerAddBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(mActivity);
            chooseImageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, pickImageId);
        });
```

**ImagePicker.class**

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), context.getString(R.string.image_pickerOptions));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

**Handle result from picker**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != 0) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case NewRequestActivity.PICK_IMAGE_ID_1:
                onActivityResultImagePicker(0, imagePicker1, imagePickerDeleteBtn1, resultCode, data, imagePickerAddBtn1);
                break;
            case NewRequestActivity.PICK_IMAGE_ID_2:
                onActivityResultImagePicker(1, imagePicker2, imagePickerDeleteBtn2, resultCode, data, imagePickerAddBtn2);
                break;
            case NewRequestActivity.PICK_IMAGE_ID_3:
                onActivityResultImagePicker(2, imagePicker3, imagePickerDeleteBtn3, resultCode, data, imagePickerAddBtn3);
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void onActivityResultImagePicker(int index, ImageButton imagePicker, ImageButton imagePickerDeleteBtn, int resultCode, Intent data, ImageButton imagePickerAddBtn) {
    imagePickerAddBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imagePickerDeleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imagePicked.add(index, ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(mActivity, resultCode, data));
    imagePicker.setImageBitmap(imagePicked.get(imagePicked.size() - 1));
}
```

**getImageFromResult**

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getImageFromResult, resultCode: " + resultCode);
    Bitmap bm = null;
    File imageFile = getTempFile(context);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage;
        boolean isCamera = (imageReturnedIntent == null ||
                imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null  ||
                imageReturnedIntent.getData().toString().contains(imageFile.toString()));
        if (isCamera) {     /** CAMERA **/
            selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        } else {            /** ALBUM **/
            selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "selectedImage: " + selectedImage);

        bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage);
        int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, isCamera);
        bm = rotate(bm, rotation);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

**Resize to avoid using too much memory loading big images (e.g.: 2560*1920)**

```
private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    int[] sampleSizes = new int[]{5, 3, 2, 1};
    int i = 0;
    do {
        bm = decodeBitmap(context, selectedImage, sampleSizes[i]);
        Log.d(TAG, "resizer: new bitmap width = " + bm.getWidth());
        i++;
    } while (bm.getWidth() < DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY && i < sampleSizes.length);
    return bm;
}


private static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Context context, Uri theUri, int sampleSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

    Log.d(TAG, options.inSampleSize + " sample method bitmap ... " +
            actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth() + " " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight());

    return actuallyUsableBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Can you first explain what you are trying to do before dumping all that code?

Comment: `chooseImageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` That flag makes no sense. You better remove it.

Comment: Why are you messing around with (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE if your question is about ACTION_PICK? Please post only relevant code. Remove not used code. Remove the camera code. Dont make it so difficult for us to read all your code.

Comment: Yes I explained. If the user selected an image regretted and wants to select another image then it does not work, see an example in the attached image.

Comment: That is no explanation. You should explain first what your code should do. For instance: why should an image be repicked? And what are you doing with the picked images?

Comment: 1. Create new post in my app.
2. Add an image to that post.
3. Change the selected image.

Comment: To explain how your app should work put all info in your post. Dont use comments for that. Put it before dumping your code.

Comment: I do not really understand what is wrong with my explanation. Let's try it another way, do you have an example of how I choose an image from the gallery or camera and get a bitmap in return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223694/discussion-between-shachar87-and-blackapps).

Comment: `I select an image at the first time and everything works fine.` Apparently you know how to get a bitmap as otherwise it would not work the first time. Further we cannot see what you do in `getImageResized` which you better could name `getBitmapResized`. I will not chat.

Comment: I updated the post with getImageResized.